# Json key value mapping with array object

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to map an array of object with JSON object to show the field name:

I have Array of objects

```
    [
  {
    _id: "535345345345345345311",
    name: "Activity",
    description: "this is activity",
    filters: []
  },
  {
    _id: "535345345345345345311",
    name: "Activity",
    description: "this is activity",
    filters: [
      { _id: "49823476237423984", name: "ACTIVITY filter", origin: "ACTIVITY" }
    ]
  }
];
```

And trying to map with the data JSON, (maping `origin` of `filters` in above)

```
{
  "user_of": "User",
  "student_of": "Student",
  "test_of": "TEST"
}
```

Here, like that array of object have `user_of` then it should show `User` Reading data from the json. Or if data is not present at the JSON then show origin.
Like if there's data `example_of` its there in that above array object, but not in JSON then show `example_of` only....

I am trying this with below code

```
{record.filters.map((filter, index) => (
          <>
            {index < 2 && (
              <span style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}>
                {filter.origin.toLowerCase()}
                {index === 0 && record.filters.length > 1 && <span>, </span>}
              </span>
            )}
          </>
        ))}
        {record.filters.length > 2 && (
          <span> +{record.filters.length - 2} </span>
        )}
```

But unable to match it, Also here's https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-kilby-hhbon?file=/index.js:490-924 link for details I am trying to achieve, where I have kept one JSON file from where i have to map the data.

Can anyone help me with this?
Just new to JS (Previously worked with Python)

Edit-

I am getting this right now
[image]

And what I expect is (the value I want to map from JSON file)
[image]

Comment: Ciao, sorry I don't understand what you are trying to do. I saw the codesandbox . Supposing that codesandbox result is what you don't want, can you show me what do you want instead? Thanks :)

Comment: So Want to do is now if you check table filter column, you see now its getting `activity_of` now I want to read data from JSON(in that codesandbox example.json), I want to show Activity with has key `activity_of` in JSON. so this I want to do with every mapping I do. I want to map value with key of json to the value.
Like `activity_of` would show Activity (JSON value data) at table.

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito Also updated the question for better understandingg